# How to execute a .exe file from python file

Tags: python, subprocess, exe

I am trying to open google.com with Internet Explorer. This is my program:

```
import subprocess

arg = ['runas', '/user:Administrator',
        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe", "www.google.com"]
subprocess.call(arg)
```

I saved this file as `shortform.py` and executed it. The program worked but it doesn't show any output. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
import subprocess

arg = ['runas', '/user:Administrator', "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe www.google.com"]
subprocess.call(arg)
```